# values unnecessarily rounded

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have some database figures that I am doing some simple math with.  For some reason, I can't keep the total from rounding to the nearest dollar.  I need to include the cents information, as well, though.  I am positive that each itemPrice entry contains two decimal places in the database.

```
if (strpos($row2["itemDiscount"],'%') !== false) {
    $itemDiscount = $row2["itemDiscount"];
    $itemDetailTotalUnformatted = $row2["itemQuantity"]*($itemPrice*(1-($itemDiscount/100)));
}
else {
    $itemDetailTotalUnformatted = $row2["itemQuantity"]*($row2["itemPrice"]-$row2["itemDiscount"]);
}
$itemDetailTotal = number_format($itemDetailTotalUnformatted, 2, '.', '');
echo $itemDetailTotal;
```

var_dump($row2):

```
50.00array(6) {
[0]=>
string(1) "2"
"itemQuantity"]=>
string(1) "2"
[1]=>
string(5) "30.00"
[itemPrice]=>
string(1) "30.00"
[2]=>
string(4) "5.00"
[itemPrice]=>
string(4) "5.00"
```

Comment: Do a vardump on $row2 please.

Comment: have you tried converting the database response fields to floats first?  Data coming back from your db will be String data.

Comment: @jon interesting, though it is doing the math correctly, so it definitely recognizes everything as numbers.

Comment: So what changes if you cast all of your $row[] responses to float in your $itemDiscount and $itemDetailTotal lines?

Comment: did any of you read this code? @radleybobins can you give us a working example that shows the problem this code echo's `0.00` aka empty string.

Comment: Am I missing something or is `$itemDetailTotalUnformatted` only defined in the second block?

Comment: @tigrang oh wow, you are correct...but it didn't change any results

Comment: @tyler var_dump posted to original post

Comment: @Louis so I put in 1 for quantity, $30.00 for price, and $5.03 for discount and it echos "24.00"

Comment: @Jon Any solutions assuming I can't change the current database format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with currency, ALWAYS work in integers. Save the prices in cents, handle prices in cents, and only at the very end do you divide by 100 to present the result.

The reason for this is that ints have perfect precision (up to obscenely high values, where they are handled as floats instead), whereas floats do not. There is no fixed-point type in PHP.

Once you do that, your rounding problems will probably disappear.

Comment: thank you, I will start rearranging now...but the thing is that I'm pulling numbers off the database as decimals already...i know this seems silly, but maybe I can get around this by multiplying by 100 immediately and then handling it the rest of the way with integers.  Both itemPrice and itemDiscount appear correctly in the databse, its just not doing math quite right.

Comment: In that case you need to update the database to use integers too. Either that, or if you know they have two decimal places (ie. you're using a `decimal` column), you might be able to get away with just `str_replace`'ing the decimal point away.

Comment: yeah, okay, I think we had similar ideas we were typing at the same time.  The reason I can't replace the database is because I'm creating a new backend for a site that already has a frontend and database.  I have a feeling I would mess things up on the other side if I started editing the db.